# Declarative Initialization list width kendo autocomplete

Tags: autocomplete, kendo-ui, declarative

Is there any way to decoratively define the List width in the HTML. 
I know I can do it

```js
var autoComplete = $("#autoComplete").data("kendoAutoComplete");

// set width of the drop-down list
autoComplete.list.width(400);
```

but I want to do it in HTML only.
I have already tried:

```js
data-list-width="400"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the answer from telerik today:

*Currently, the width of the popup element can be set only programatically.*

Comment: Somehow disagree, as you can see in http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/n55w8/ you can do it also via CSS. Depends how you formulate the question you get different answers.

Comment: By declaratively I mean not using the JavaScript neither using CSS. (http://docs.kendoui.com/howto/declarative_initialization#declarative-initialization).

Answer (score 2):

When you create an `autocomplete` in Kendo UI, it creates a second HTML element (a wrapper) for the drop down options. This element is given as `id` the `id` of the original one plus `-list`.

You can define a CSS style for this newly created wrapper as:

```css
#autocomplete-list {
    width: 300px !important;
}
```

You need to use `!important` otherwise the value calculated by Kendo UI has prevalence over yours.

Example in this JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/n55w8/

Comment: As I was using MVVM I didn't have to add a name for my AutoComplete and now I have to. But it's working.

Comment: You don't have to add an `id`. You need to identify the element to assign the width. If there is no other autocomplete in the page you can use a generic CSS selector `.k-list-container`. Example : http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/n55w8/1/

Comment: Yes, I know I can find it using the CSS selector. Actually, I had to use your solution as defining style until Telerik give a declarative solution.

Answer (score 0):

Salam!

The `.width(400)` is not a configuration setting, it is [jQuery width](http://api.jquery.com/width/) method, so you can't set width for your autocomplete decoratively.

If you use MVVM framework in your project, maybe [Custom binding](http://docs.kendoui.com/getting-started/framework/mvvm/bindings/custom) help you to add a custom binding like `<input id="autoComplete" data-bind="listwidth: 400" />` for your autocomplete.

See [this demo](http://demos.kendoui.com/web/mvvm/custom.html) if you want to use custom binding.